# How to handle escaped sequences in JSON array with express

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

I am using node.js with express and I'm building an API that exposes an endpoint that must accept POST requests with a a JSON array of strings.

I'm having problems when I receive JSON arrays with special escaped characters like this one:

```
[\t"hello"\n, "world"\n\n]
```

Is there any way to ignore or parse this with express? I thought that `app.use(express.json());` could handle this.

Everytime I receive one JSON array with escape characters it gives me this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token \ in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at parse (...\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:89:19)
```

Comment: Escape sequences should only be inside strings. You should fix whatever is creating that JSON.

Comment: You can't use escape characters in JSON DATA

Answer (score 2):

Show me the code creating the JSON. Then I'll help you solve the problem, because working with existing JSON like that isn't right. JSON only should have something like:

```
{
 "name1": "value1",
 "name2": "value2",
 "name3": "value3",
 ...,
 "namex": "valuex"
}
```

Never let values go outside the quotemarks if they're a string.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the json returned in response api is string so looks like that => [\t"hello"\n, "world"\n\n].
Do you parse it already?

```js
const array = `[\t"hello"\n, "world"\n\n]`
const parseArray = JSON.parse(array)

console.log(parseArray)
```